# Use Vue.js with ReactiveSearch in existing project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an existing web appliction that is not taking advantage of any existing reactive 
frameworks or technology (like Angular, Vue or React).
I want use Vue.js with the ReactiveSearch opensource libary without rewriting my whole application.

While working through the tutorial (https://docs.appbase.io/docs/reactivesearch/vue/overview/QuickStart/) I encountered the following problem:
I can't use the components of the ReactiveSearch-Libary and I don't know why.
In my example I want create a multi-list component as described in the tutorial.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@appbaseio/reactivesearch-vue@1.0.0-beta.19/dist/@appbaseio/reactivesearch-vue.umd.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
   <div id="app">
  <reactive-base app="good-books-ds" credentials="nY6NNTZZ6:27b76b9f-18ea-456c-bc5e-3a5263ebc63d">
     <h1>Hello from ReactiveBase</h1>
     <multi-list
    componentId="Authors"
    dataField="authors.raw"
    class="filter"
    title="Select Authors"
    selectAllLabel="All Authors"
   />
  </reactive-base>
   </div> 
<script>

import { ReactiveBase } from '@appbaseio/reactivesearch-vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(ReactiveBase);

const vueApp = new Vue({
 el: '#app'
})

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I get following error message:
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Comment: try `<script type="module">`

Comment: Then I get this message: TypeError: Error resolving module specifier: @appbaseio/reactivesearch-vue

Comment: ok, undo that - then read how to use vue-cli